# order should be paid before save or not?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I have a logical question about magento checkout

is orders should be saved after a payment received or not?

i saw there is a placeOrder function in js files of paypal braintree or even simplegateway module ! ... is it called before payment received by this modules or not?